# Can't make bootstrap modal work. Using PHP the get data and display it using a modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal

Using PHP, I am trying to get data and display it using a bootstrap modal.

I can't get the bootstrap modal to open.

My PHP code connects to the server and database, and sends the information back, but since the modal does not work, it can't display the data received.

I also tried to activate the modal using JavaScript, but it still did not work.

Here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<div id="head">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen">
    <title> IUC Alumni Connect </title>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="http://www.aci.k12.tr" target="_blank"><img id="JLogo" src="ACILogo.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h1 id="JTitle" class="greeting"><b> Welcome to the IUC Reachout Page </b></h1>
                    <p id="JExplanation" class="greeting"> Find alumni, contact them, make the right choices.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <style>
        .modal-header, h4, .close {
            background-color: #5cb85c;
            color: white !important;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        .modal-footer {
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }
    </style>
</div>
<body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
                    <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Results</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
                    <?php
                    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]="GET"){
                    if (isset($_GET['uni_name']) && is_string($_GET['uni_name'])) {
                    $uname = $_GET['uni_name'];
                    } else {
                    $uname = "";
                    }
                    }

                    $con = mysqli_connect('', '', '', '');

                    if ($con->connect_errno) {
                    echo "
                    <script> alert('We are experiencing problems.') </script>";
                    exit;
                    }

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE university like '%".$uname."%'";

                    if (!$result = $con->query($sql)) {
                    echo "
                    <script> alert('Sorry, the website is experiencing problems.') </script>";
                    exit;
                    }
                    if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
                    echo "
                    <script> alert('We could not find a match for ID ".$uname.", sorry about that. Please attempt again.') </script>";
                    exit;
                    } else {
                    echo "<ul>
                        ";
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo sprintf("
                        <li>%s %s - %s</li>", $row["firstName"], $row["lastName"], $row["university"]);
                        //echo sprintf("
                        <li>%s</li>", $row["lastName"]);
                        //echo sprintf("
                        <li>%s</li>", $row["university"]);
                        }
                        echo "
                    </ul>";
                    }

                    $result->free();
                    $con->close();
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button onclick="graduateYearPage.html" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Return to search </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onclick="graduateYearPage.html"` that's failing here (and for more than one reason). You need to call a function for that, and not a file. You can also `.load()` the contents into that modal; too many ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason it is not working is because "Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3". Then you can in your own words "activate it using javascript" (jQuery).

There's a lot wrong with your HTML as well, but even while leaving that in place, using for example jQuery 1.12.4 makes the difference (left out your PHP):

```
<html lang="en">
    <div id="head">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen">
        <title> IUC Alumni Connect </title>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a href="http://www.aci.k12.tr" target="_blank"><img id="JLogo" src="ACILogo.png" alt=""></a> 
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h1 id="JTitle" class="greeting" ><b> Welcome to the IUC Reachout Page </b></h1>
                        <p id="JExplanation" class="greeting"> Find alumni, contact them, make the right choices.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <style>
            .modal-header, h4, .close {
                background-color: #5cb85c;
                color:white !important;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 30px;
            }
            .modal-footer {
                background-color: #f9f9f9;
            }
        </style>
    </div>
    <body>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
                    <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Results</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Put your php code here</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button onclick="graduateYearPage.html" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Return to search </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script  type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal();
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```